# Understanding multiple parameter groups in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand the below method in scala

```
def apply[T](ctx: SomeContext)(constructor: Something => MyCheck[T]): MyCheck[T] = {
  ctx.something match {
    case Some(something) => constructor(something)
    case None => new MyCheck
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- What does the `=>` inside the second parameter group represent? i.e. `(constructor: Something => MyCheck[T])`
- If I remove `=> MyCheck[T]` from the parameter group then the return type is complained upon

Answer (score 1):

- `X => Y` is a function type `Function1[X, Y]`.

  https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Function1.scala

  For example `val f: Int => Double = (x: Int) => x * 1.0`. Here `(x: Int) => x * 1.0` is a lambda (anonymous function), `Int => Double` is its type.

  `constructor: Something => MyCheck[T]` means that method `apply`'s parameter `constructor` has type of function from `Something` to `MyCheck[T]`.
- Then don't remove `=> MyCheck[T]`. If you remove `=> MyCheck[T]` then `constructor` becomes of type `Something` instead of `Something => MyCheck[T]` and you can't call it like `constructor(something)`.

The following code compiles:

```
trait SomeContext {
  def something: Option[Something]
}
trait Something
class MyCheck[T]

def apply[T](ctx: SomeContext)(constructor: Something => MyCheck[T]): MyCheck[T] = {
  ctx.something match {
    case Some(something) => constructor(something)
    case None => new MyCheck
  }
}
```

Multiple parameter groups `ctx: SomeContext` and `constructor: Something => MyCheck[T]` mean that you can invoke `apply` with parameter `ctx` and get a function

```
apply(ctx): (Something => MyCheck[T]) => MyCheck[T]
```

or invoke `apply` with `ctx` and then with `constructor` and get a value

```
apply(ctx)(constructor): MyCheck[T]
```

This is called currying https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/multiple-parameter-lists.html